# Mock a method bean to avoid NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a method bean that reads a file and returns a NullPointerException when the file doesn't exist. When I am running tests, I don't expect that file to exist so I want to mock that method bean to return a dummy response. It doesn't seem to be working however, and I'm getting an error like this:

```
"class":"o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext"
,"rest":"Exception encountered during context initialization - 
cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'someName' defined in class path resource
 [../../Someconfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [className]: Factory method 'someName' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"}
```

The method looks like this:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier(SOME_QUALIFIER)
public className someName() {
    // read file and return null exception if it doesn't exist
}
```

Would appreciate any ideas on fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a use case for [Spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles).

Mark this method with a positive profile that is only active in production, or a negative profile that is only active in test:

```
@Bean @Profile("production")
@Qualifier(SOME_QUALIFIER)
public className someName() {
```

or

```
@Bean @Profile("!test")
@Qualifier(SOME_QUALIFIER)
public className someName() {
```

of course you will have to substitute a test configuration that is active for the test profile.